# How to use a route helper method from a file in the lib directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to use the `root_url` method from a method defined in a file in the `lib` folder. Is that possible?

I tried including this line in my class:

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

but this gives me the error

> Missing host to link to! Please provide :host parameter or set default_url_options[:host]

---

**Edit:** I found out that it works if I first initialize the routes:

```
def initialize_routes
  if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?
    Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000' 
  elsif Rails.env.production?
    Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'example.com'
  end
end
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this? Maybe setting the routes in a config file?

Comment: This answer really helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16728549/2639304

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There should be a couple solutions for this.

1) when using root_url pass in the host param like:

```
root_url(:host => 'localhost')
```

That would need to be made to be environment specific though.

2) You should also be able to set the routes default_url_options like:

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host]= 'localhost:3000'
```

3) Within your environment config files you should set the default_url_options as stated in the error.  For example:

In `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost'
```

In `config/environments/test.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost'
```

In `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host] = 'production.com'
```

Comment: #1 and #2 work great. Although #3 doesn't. #2 sounds like the best workaround. I'll leave the answer open to see if someone knows how to set this up from the config files. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 29):

@JDutil's #3 solution, as mentioned in the comments, is configuring the action mailer and not the router's routes. However, in the configuration you can perform the following:

In `config/environments/development.rb` and `config/environments/test.rb`:

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  # other configuration ...
  config.after_initialize do
    Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'
  end
end
```

Comment: `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options` maybe even

Comment: It is not even those two

Answer (score 6):

If you're relying on `url_helpers` for something like `ActiveModel::Serializers` (at least the v0.9.* series) where you'll be generating URLs outside of the main Rails request/response flow, you'll also need to set the `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options`. I've done it like so,

```rb
# config/application.rb

config.after_initialize do
  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = config.action_mailer.default_url_options
end
```

The url helpers are now available, with a default host, in places like background jobs, etc...

Comment: Pointing to the existing `default_url_options` is great in this case. It solves the issue for all of my environments.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same issue and none of the configuration suggestions worked. Thing that left me confused is that url_helpers works just fine from other parts of the application (specifically helpers). So I shouldn't have to insert new configuration to be able to use them elsewhere.

My solution at the end of the day was to do this:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.athlete_url(athlete)
```

What I suspect, though I can't prove, is that including the url helpers manually with:

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

actually causes some `included` block to be executed. Doing so changes the configuration out from under the code trying to use it. By not including, but instead referring to it directly any 'included' blocks are not re-executed.

I'd love to know if anyone can explain if I'm on the right track or just making false assumptions.

Bottom line though, referring to the url_helpers with the full module/class path got the job done.