# How to use url helpers in lib modules, and set host for multiple environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 3.2 app I need to access url_helpers in a `lib` file. I'm using

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.model_url(model)
```

but I'm getting

```
ArgumentError (Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true):
```

I've found a few things written about this, but nothing that really explains how to solve this for multiple environments.

i.e. I assume I need to add something to my development.rb and production.rb files, but what?

Closest I've seen to an answer suggested using `config.action_mailer.default_url_option`, but this does not work outside of action mailer.

What is the correct way to set the host for multiple environments?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is a problem that I keep running into and has bugged me for a while.

I know many will say it goes against the MVC architecture to access url_helpers in models and modules, but there are times—such as when interfacing with an external API—where it does make sense.

After much searching I've found an answer!

```
#lib/routing.rb

module Routing
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  included do
    def default_url_options
      ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options
    end
  end
end

#lib/url_generator.rb

class UrlGenerator
  include Routing
end
```

I can now call the following in any model, module, class, console, etc

```
UrlGenerator.new.models_url
```

Result!

Comment: I can confirm this works, but I got a nasty error where I had a class with a method `def self.name`. When creating a route from an instance of this class, the url generator would blow up. Solution: rename `def self.name` to something else.

Comment: The link to the great blog post is no longer a great link. Consider removing it. It is nsfw.

Answer (score 17):

A slight improvement (at least for me) on Andy's lovely answer

```
module UrlHelpers

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class Base
    include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

    def default_url_options
      ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options
    end
  end

  def url_helpers
    @url_helpers ||= UrlHelpers::Base.new
  end

  def self.method_missing method, *args, &block
    @url_helpers ||= UrlHelpers::Base.new

    if @url_helpers.respond_to?(method)
      @url_helpers.send(method, *args, &block)
    else
      super method, *args, &block
    end
  end

end
```

and the way you use it is:

```
include UrlHelpers
url_helpers.posts_url # returns https://blabla.com/posts
```

or simply

```
UrlHelpers.posts_url # returns https://blabla.com/posts
```

Thank you Andy! +1

Comment: I couldn't get this working unless I did `require 'url_helpers'` in the file that I needed it in.

Comment: If you need your url helpers to take locale into consideration, I'd rewrite the `UrlHelpers::Base#default_url_options` method above to `{ locale: I18n.locale == I18n.default_locale ? nil : I18n.locale }.merge( ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options )`. @bbozo can you take a look at it ?

Answer (score 6):

Use this string in any module controller to get application URL-helpers works in any view or controller.

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

Please note, some internal module url-helpers should be namespaced.

**Example:**
root application

> routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
get 'action' =>  "contr#action", :as => 'welcome'
mount Eb::Core::Engine => "/" , :as => 'eb'
end
```

Url helpers in module Eb:

```
users_path
```

Add `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` in controller `contr`

So after that helper should be

```
eb.users_path
```

So inside Eb module you can use `welcome_path` same as in root application!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this works in Rails 3.2, but in later versions setting default url options for the routes can be done **directly** on the routes instance.

So for example, to set the same options as for ActionMailer:

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options
```

Comment: I added this to an initializer.  In my opinion, the other answers are incomplete without this because you need the host in order to use the `*_url` helpers, and it's probably already setup to send email.