# rails activerecord concern, including url helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Im trying to create an before_save callback for certain models that will add links and formatting to text and that gets saved in a special field.  It won't let me include the URL helpers in the callback.

Here's my code:

```
module SocialText
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_save :action_before_save
  end

  def action_before_save
    self.body_formatted = htmlizeBody(self.body)
  end

  def htmlizeBody(body)
    include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
    include ActionView::Helpers

    #replace all \ns with <br>
    body = body.gsub(/\n/, ' <br/> ')

    words = body.split(/\s/)
    words.map! do |word|
      if word.first == '@'
        username = extractUsernameFromAtSyntax word
        user = User.find_by! username: username

        if not user.nil?
          link_to(word, profile_path(user.username))
        else
          word
        end
      else
        word
      end
    end

    words.join " "
  end

  def extractUsernameFromAtSyntax(username)
    matchData = username.match(/@(\w+)(['.,]\w*)?/)

    if not matchData.nil?
      matchData[1]
    else
      username
    end
  end
end
```

I'm getting:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `include`)
```

How do I get the helper?  is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `include` operates on a class instance object and you call it like an instance method.

You should take that `include` part outside of your methods.

Comment: i have done that, and moved it to the module level, but I'm now getting "ArgumentError (arguments passed to url_for can't be handled. Please require routes or provide your own implementation)" when the server attempts to call "profile_path".  This code works when outside the concern.

Comment: I had to rearrange the includes, then it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `htmlizeBody` function:

`include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
include ActionView::Helpers`

This is in the wrong scope, moving it underneath `extend ActiveSupport::Concern` will resolve your error.

Another question you could ask yourself is why you need to use view helpers at the concern level?

`include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` is usually used when modifying the default url host options (typically when you need to interface with an external API). In this case, it would make sense to use it in the `/lib` directory.

See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720514/how-to-use-url-helpers-in-lib-modules-and-set-host-for-multiple-environments) and [this post on using url helpers](http://hawkins.io/2012/03/generating_urls_whenever_and_wherever_you_want/) for more info

Answer (score 0):

`include` operates on a class instance object and you call it like an instance method.

You should take that `include` part outside of your methods.

Consider using `require` at your module scope.